# Obtain /common/topic/description in Freebase MQL

Tags: freebase, mql

Good day,

how can I obtain the topic text description in Freebase? For example, I ask MQL query about Chernobyl disaster:

```
[{
  "type": "/common/topic",
  "description": null,
  "mid": "/m/07q37w"
}]
```

but obtain null description. At the same time I can see non-null description at Freebase page: http://www.freebase.com/m/07q37w

Answer (score 4):

`/common/topic/description` is a pseudo-property which is not accessible through MQL.  You can use the Topic API as follows:

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/m/07q37w?filter=/common/topic/description

Comment: Thank you, but I've mentioned MQL in text and in tag. I'll add it to topic too. I'm interested, why I can't see description namely in MQL response. And, as I can see, text API is deprecated? I can't see it at https://developers.google.com/freebase/

Comment: Sorry about that. I missed the lower case mql when reading.  I've edited the question to uppercase them and added an alternate API that you can use if you don't want to use the Text API.

Comment: Apparently, although Google hadn't officially announced it yet, the Text API is going away, so I've removed that from my answer.

Comment: Thank you for link to Topic API. Still, I want to use MQL because it's far more flexible and allows to get exactly what I need (full query contains not only description). I'm trying to understand, what's wrong with my MQL query and how to obtain description with it.

Comment: So add the other stuff that you want to the Topic API's filter.  As my answer says, /common/topic/description isn't a property, so it's not available through MQL.