# Get list of dishes and detail per dish page in Freebase?

Tags: json, node.js, api, rdf, freebase

I tried this query to get the list of all dish instances

```
[{
  "id": null,
  "name": null,
  "type": "/food/dish"
}]
```

But it only gives me first page:

http://www.freebase.com/query?autorun=1&q=%5B%7B%22id%22:null,%22name%22:null,%22type%22:%22/food/dish%22%7D%5D

**Question 1:** How to add paging to get all 2.5K or so dish instances? I tried to add "cursor: 2" and didn't work.

---

Let say I have a name "pizza", I tried this query to get detail of "pizza":

```
{
  "*": null,
  "name": "pizza",
  "type": "/food/dish"
}
```

But that didn't give me description and images like this page http://www.freebase.com/m/0663v

**Question 2:** How to get all information, or at least description and image URLs like in the freebase page above?

**Bonus**: I tried to do everything via Freebase Node.js here https://github.com/spencermountain/Freebase.js

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you separate this into 2 questions, so each has their own topic, and it is easier for future visitors to search.

That said:

## Question 1

You can increase the number of results you get per page by adding `limit:` to your query. Regardless, you will have to use paging. To use paging, you need to add the `cursor` parameter to your `mqlread` HTTP request. Again: `cursor` is *not* part of the MQL query itself, but rather of the HTTP envelope that submits it.

For the first query, issue an empty `cursor`, and for subsequent queries use the `cursor` value returned to you by mqlread.

Note that all this will need to be done with the API, not with freebase directly, and as such the URL will need to be:

`https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?cursor=&query=[{"id":null,"name":null,"type":"/food/dish","limit":5}]`

Also note that if you plan on doing this for anything other than testing you will need to obtain a key from Google.

Finally, note that some strings in Freebase are "freebase-encoded", read up on that regarding how to decode them in the result.

## Question 2

If you just want the ingredient names then simply add `"/dining/cuisine/ingredients": []` to your query. Note that many dishes do not have ingredients, but Pizza does:

```
{
  "id": "/m/0663v",
  "name": null,
  "type": "/food/dish",
  "/dining/cuisine/ingredients": []
}
```

Getting the images means adding `"/common/topic/image": [{}]` to your query, and using the returned `id` for each image.

Getting an image URL from a given image `id` is done by prepending `https://usercontent.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/image/` to the `id`.

## Edit

Tom correctly noted that I forgot about image descriptions. The description for each image will be available under `name:` in the returned `/common/topic/image` array. For example, for the query

```
[{
  "id": "/en/minestrone",
  "/common/topic/image": [{
    "id": null,
    "name": null
  }]
}]
```

you get the following images and their descriptions:

```
{
  "result": [{
    "id": "/en/minestrone",
    "/common/topic/image": [
      {
        "id": "/wikipedia/images/commons_id/1492185",
        "name": "MinestroneSoup"
      },
      {
        "id": "/wikipedia/images/commons_id/12565901",
        "name": "Homemade minestrone"
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

Your final MQL, then, is:

```
[{
  "id": null,
  "name": null,
  "type": "/food/dish",
  "/common/topic/image": [{
    "id": null,
    "name": null
  }],
  "/dining/cuisine/ingredients": []
}]
```

... and the HTTP envelope will contain a key and a value for `cursor`.

Comment: Actually I tried to pull the description of the dish too but the following doesn't work: `[{
  "id": "/en/minestrone",
  "/common/topic/description": [{
    "id": null,
    "name": null
  }]
}]` Any clue?

Comment: My apologies, I seem to have misunderstood your meaning when you said "description". At any rate, the description for the topic isn't directly available from MQL, as Tom said. You would need to use the topic API, as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732247/obtain-common-topic-description-in-freebase-mql, or get the "/common/topic/article" property and get that article.

Answer (score 1):

See Nitzan's answer for the answer to question 1.

For your second question, the easiest way to get descriptions and images is by using the [Topic API](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/topic-overview)  e.g. https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/m/0663v

Comment: Given that he is already issuing a query, I thought it would be easiest to get everything back in one place, and also save queries.

Comment: They asked for both images and descriptions as well which is going to mean a separate query to the text API while the Topic API will include that information directly.

Comment: Actually the description is also available from mql. I'll edit my answer when I'm in front of my laptop.